# React Center div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using react to build a dialog component, and i want to be able to calculate left and top to center the fixed dialog position.

I know that

```js
left= windowWidth/2 -(dialogWidth /2)
```

the problem is that the dialog width is dynamicly generated.

How to i calculate the dialog width.

Im not after using css i want to use react or javascript to get those data.

Here is my current components

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { any } from 'prop-types';

export default class Dialog extends React.PureComponent<{
    children: React.ReactDOM,
    isOpen?: Boolean,
    title?: string,
    save?: Function
}>
{
    public state = {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        isOpen: this.props.isOpen
    }


    public toggle() {
        /// Calculate position and toggld open
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="dialog" style={{ left: this.state.left, top: this.state.top, display: (this.state.isOpen ?"block": "hidden") }}>
                <h2 className="header">{this.props.title}
                    <span className="btn"></span>
                </h2>
                <div className="center"></div>
            </div>
        )


    }
}
```

left me know what you think

Comment: _I'm not after using css i want to use react or javascript to get those data._ – Why is that? There are very straightforward CSS alternatives.

Comment: This can be easily than with CSS mate, you should stick to that.

Comment: ok show me a css solution that will take the size of the dialog into account

Answer (score 0):

You can reach an element's width anytime by `element.clientWidth`. So `(window.innerWidth - element.clientWidth) / 2` should give you the space on the left of your element. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: With Javascript, either `document.querySelector('elementName')` or `document.querySelector('.className')` or `document.querySelector('#id')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok got a solution using reactDOM

here is how

```
   var el = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this) as HTMLElement;
            var offset = el.getElementsByClassName("dialog")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
            var left = window.outerWidth / 2 - (offset.width / 2);
            var top = window.outerHeight / 2 - (offset.height / 2);
            this.setState({ left: left, top: top });
```